# how to hide specific cog from custom help command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have such help command and I wonder how to make "owner" cog hidden from help command

````
   @commands.hybrid_command(
        name="help", description="Список всех доступных команд бота."
    )
    @checks.not_blacklisted()
    async def help(self, context: Context) -> None:
        prefix = self.bot.config["prefix"]
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Помощь", description="Список доступных команд:", color=0x9C84EF
        )
        for i in self.bot.cogs:
            cog = self.bot.get_cog(i.lower())
            commands = cog.get_commands()  
            data = []
            for command in commands:
                description = command.description.partition("\n")[0]
                data.append(f"{prefix}{command.name} - {description}")
            help_text = "\n".join(data)
            embed.add_field(
                name=i.capitalize(), value=f"```{help_text}```", inline=False
            )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
````

I treid few options to make this possible but they didn't work so I need help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with adding

```
if cog is None or cog.qualified_name.lower() not in VISIBLE_COGS:
    continue
```

so now it looks like this

```
for i in self.bot.cogs:
    cog = self.bot.get_cog(i.lower())
    commands = cog.get_commands()
    data = []

    if cog is None or cog.qualified_name.lower() not in VISIBLE_COGS:
        continue
```